# Thought today was Eid and had no intent to fast - what now

Tags: sawm, ramadan

Selam alleykum everyone,

I have a very stupid one:
As many of you I have been working from home and kind of lost my feeling of time. Elhamdullilah I was able to fast every day — except for today. I was sure, that today would be eid and did not fast today. Only when I called my mother to tell her that I was on my way I realized my mistake.
So what do I do now? I cannot just pretend I did not have my breakfast and continue until dawn - I clearly had no intend to fast today. Consider this:

> "There is no fast for the one who does not intend to fast before dawn."
>
> Reference : Sunan an-Nasa'i 2338

So do I really need to fast 60 days in retribution as payment for my stupidity? This seems like a rare case so I do not even know where to begin my research :(
Thank you all for your time

Comment: We are no fatwa site. But be aware that nevertheless you must continue your day fasting otherwise your sin is even worse. I'd assume that at least according to the Maliki view you must take the harder kaffarah for intentionally breaking your fast. Because they consider the intention binding however they accept an intention for the whole month in opposition to other madhhabs. As long as you have Bo certainty about 'Id you must be ready to fast as the fiqh rule says who has doubt must rely on his certainty and do far it was certainly still Ramadan without an announcement.

Comment: [Here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/60614/13438)'s a similar case.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a fatwa site. An apporpriate answer requires more information.